# Table manipulation

Tags: export

This might be an odd way of output, but I want to output this way so I can use the format from my fortran code:

Say I have

t1 = Table[f[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}]

t2 = Table[g[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}]

which gives

t1 = {{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 1], 
  f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}}

t2 = {{g[1, 1], g[1, 2], g[1, 3]}, {g[2, 1], g[2, 2], g[2, 3]}, {g[3, 1], 
  g[3, 2], g[3, 3]}}

My hope is to output this as two column of data in following form :

f[1,1] g[1,1]

f[1,2] g[1,2]

f[1,3] g[1,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t1 = Array[f, {3, 3}];
t2 = Array[g, {3, 3}];

ExportString[Flatten[{t1, t2}, {2, 3}], "Table"]
```

> ```
> f[1, 1]   g[1, 1]
> f[1, 2]   g[1, 2]
> f[1, 3]   g[1, 3]
> f[2, 1]   g[2, 1]
> f[2, 2]   g[2, 2]
> f[2, 3]   g[2, 3]
> f[3, 1]   g[3, 1]
> f[3, 2]   g[3, 2]
> f[3, 3]   g[3, 3]
> ```

Comment: (Change `ExportString[]` to `Export[]` if one wants the output in a file.)

Comment: @J.M. Oh, yes, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

```
t1 = Table[f[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}] // Flatten
t2 = Table[g[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3}}, {y, {1, 2, 3}}] // Flatten

Export["data.dat", Transpose[{t1,t2}], "Table"]
```